# Fatal error in Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory::getProxy()

Tags: orm, symfony, annotations, doctrine-orm

Hey I am working on a symfony2 project and trying to create routes using annotations but I am getting an error but when I use to define routes from routes.yml file everything works fine but causing a problem with annotations
The error is

> Fatal error: Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory::getProxy() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/idp_svn/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundleEntityUmUsersProxy.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\idp_svn\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php on line 85

My app/congig/route.yml is

```
 MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:
  resource: "@MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle/Controller/"
  type:     annotation
  prefix:   /
  defaults:  { _controller: "MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:Default:index" }

  MunichInnovationGroupBundle:
   resource: "@MunichInnovationGroupBundle/Controller/"
   type:     annotation
   prefix:   /v1
   defaults:  { _controller: "MunichInnovationGroupBundle:Patent:index" }

   login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check

   logout:
    pattern:   /logout
```

In my controller

```
  <?php
  namespace MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Controller;

  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
  use JMS\SecurityExtraPatentBundle\Annotation\Secure;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
  use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

  use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\Log;
  use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UserPatent;
  use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\PmPortfolios;
  use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\UmUsers;
  use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Entity\PmPatentgroups;
  use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Form\PortfolioType;
  use MunichInnovationGroup\PatentBundle\Util\SecurityHelper;
  use Exception;
  /**
   * Portfolio controller.
   * @Route("/portfolio")
 */
 class PortfolioController extends Controller {
 /**
  * Index action.
  *
  * @Route("/", name="v2_pm_portfolio")
  * @Template("MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:Portfolio:index.html.twig")
*/
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager("pp_userdata");
$em->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle:PmPortfolios')
->findBy(array('user' => '$user_id'));

       // rest of the method
}
```

Any ideas? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you don't use default EntityManager? How pp_userdata is config?

Comment: @drupality I dont know what to do. I feel crying

Comment: Try use default EM, like getEntityManager();

Comment: @drupality let me give it a try

Comment: @drupality it says unknow entity namespace alias :'(

Comment: Have you checked that the given file actually exists? If not, try to regenerate proxies using `php app/console cache:clear` which warms up your cache (and generate proxies)

Comment: @Boris Guéry UmUsersProxy.php or ProxyFactory.php?

Comment: Take a look at your error message, it is written: "Failed opening required 'C:/wamp/www/idp_svn/app/cache/dev/doctrine/orm/Proxies\MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundleEntityUmUsersProxy.php'", btw Proxies\Munich... looks incorrect your proxies namespaces may be wrong.

Comment: @BorisGuéry You are right. I tried to clear my cache but it gives an error 'stty' is not a recognized command, [Reflection Exception]
Class MunichAnnoiationGroup/Bundle/PmPortfolios does not exists but actually the namespace is MunichAnnoiationGroup/PatentBundle/PmPortfolios

Comment: you could try clearing the cache manually (i.e. rm -rf app/cache/)

Comment: Clearing caches didn't help. Though putting it in prod mode worked. Why isn't it working in dev mode?